# Are you sick "at" your stomach, or sick "in" your stomach?

Tags: word-choice, expressions, prepositions, slang

When something disgusts you, are you sick **at** your stomach or sick **in** your stomach? For example, "That makes me sick ___ my stomach".

Comment: I know it makes little sense, but in the US disgusting politicians make you "sick *to* your stomach".

Comment: @Hot Licks: Same in BrE - the only US/UK split I see in [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sick+*+my+stomach&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Csick%20%2A%20my%20stomach%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsick%20to%20my%20stomach%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsick%20at%20my%20stomach%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsick%20in%20my%20stomach%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsick%20on%20my%20stomach%3B%2Cc0) is that a few people in the US corpus apparently say *sick **on** my stomach* (that's definitely a metaphoric usage too far for my delicate British sensitivities - now I really *am* revolted! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I don’t use that expression, but i’d almost interpret the ***on*** to mean “I’m so sick I’m laying  on my stomach”  the other thought makes me sick to my stomach to think about.

Comment: (It would be interesting to get a bit of the etymology of "sick to your stomach" -- I'm guessing there's a little bit of a story there.)

Comment: Sarin makes you sick *in* your stomach (and everywhere...), and war declarations make you sick *to* your stomach

Comment: @Unrelated That's semantically accurate, but you wouldn't actually describe sarin as making you sick in your stomach in those words. You'd say something along the lines of "Sblood! I've been poisonèd!" or, if you didn't realize what was wrong yet, "Zounds! My stomach feels terrible!"

Comment: Ahem - Jim should say that he is _lying_ on his stomach!

Comment: @lly If I ever find myself poisoned with sarin I will for sure say "zounds" or "sblood," just for you

Comment: @Unrelated Thank you for saying that but I think in the heat of the moment, you'll probably forget. You should probably start using them more in day-to-day conversation so it becomes second nature. ^_^

Answer (score 8):

## Sick to your stomach

In both British and American English, having a literal illness would be expressed as *having food poisoning* or *a stomachache* or *heartburn* or *ulcer* &c. You can also express it in other terms: *My stomach doesn't feel so good*, *I drank too much*, &c. A literal feeling of discomfort would be expressed as *being nauseous* or *disgusted* or *needing to* [*~10,000 euphemisms for vomit*].

In both British and American English, people say [*sick to their stomachs*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sick+*+my+stomach&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Csick%20%2A%20my%20stomach%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsick%20to%20my%20stomach%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsick%20at%20my%20stomach%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsick%20in%20my%20stomach%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsick%20on%20my%20stomach%3B%2Cc0) to express the concept of being sickened all the way to their very core. It's a way of posturing and communicating one's disagreement, but not a statement about one's actual health or need to find a nearby toilet.

Answer (score 0):

In the Mid-South, while living in Tennessee and Arkansas, I have heard "sick at" as often as not. I have even heard "sick on."

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your answer would be better if you could provide some supporting references.